# How to display multiple answers(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have made a rng(random number generator), and I want to make it into a dice generator. Thus I need multiple dice to be rolled. My problem is that every time I try to generate a number from a different "box" the previous result get overwritten. I tried changing the 'min', 'max' to be numbered, but when I do that it does not display the result. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>

        <head>
            <title>Random Number Generator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            function generateRandomNumber(){
                var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
                var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value);
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                document.getElementById('display').innerText = rand;
            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label>Min</label>
            <input id="min" type="text" /><br />
            <label>Max</label>
            <input id="max" type="text" /><br />
            <button onclick="generateRandomNumber();">Generate</button>
            <div id="display" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
        </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 7 head/body pairs in your HTML? There should only be one head and one body tag. Refactor that into one. Then give each 'display' element a unique name. You do not want to have elements with the same ID in the same doc. So make it 'display1', 'display2', etc. Then you can address properly them from your random gen function.

Comment: thanks for the input. It completely escaped me since im not used to writing code.its my second day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things here, but ***you need to have unique element id's*** if you intend to select and use these elements in any way.

I have reduced this problem down to the simplest situation, just two boxes.  Try this:

[Sample JSBin Demo](https://jsbin.com/zaraqax/edit?html,output)

Javascript...

```
function generateRandomNumber(elementid){
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('min' + elementid).value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max' + elementid).value);
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    document.getElementById('display' + elementid).innerText = rand;
}
```

HTML...

```
<label>Min</label>
<input id="min1" type="text" /><br />
<label>Max</label>
<input id="max1" type="text" /><br />
<button onclick="generateRandomNumber('1');">Generate</button>
<div id="display1" style="font-size:60px;"></div>

<label>Min</label>
<input id="min2" type="text" /><br />
<label>Max</label>
<input id="max2" type="text" /><br />
<button onclick="generateRandomNumber('2');">Generate</button>
<div id="display2" style="font-size:60px;"></div>
```

The most important thing I did was to make the id's unique.  There is no longer a `id="display"` element, but there is now an `id="display1"` and `id="display2"`.

Also: You had multiple `<HEAD/>` blocks and `<BODY/>` blocks intersecting each other.  This may not have been the main problem, but it did not help.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to not only answer my question but also providing an example.

Comment: @LittleDTLe No problem!  Welcome to stackoverflow!  Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it's truly helpful. =)